# Centering 2nd float: float left inside the div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

basically this is what my site looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/9vugv3n5/
Now i want to set the 'middle' div to be in the center of the page and the 'left' one to be left to it as 'right' one would automatically be right to the middle one. Wow this sounds confusing but i hope you get it.

```
#wrapper {
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 0;
}

#Home, #About, #Gallery, #Literature, #Contact {
text-align: center;
color: #222222;
font-family: 'source-sans';
height: calc(100% - 50px);
padding-top: 50px;
}


#Home {
background-color: #ccf0fa;
}

#About {
background-color: #c4f9de;
width: 300%;
}

#Gallery {
background-color: #dfcbff;
}

#Literature {
background-color: #fed5c8;
}

#Contact {
background-color: #fdecc8;
}


#left, #middle, #right {
width: 33.3333%;
float: left;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 50px;
}

#left {
    background-color: #000000;
}


#middle {
    background-color: #777777;
}

#right {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Then, in addition i would split the 'middle' into two divs and make it as i click the right side that it scrolls to the right and analogue to the left

EDIT: ok i see i didn't explain my problem well so i decided to draw a little sketch describing what i want exactly

http://s23.postimg.org/498qrzw63/left_middle_right.jpg

hope it's a little clearer now

Comment: Please write more about your problem or redescribe it

Comment: i edited the post now so maybe it's clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i've managed to do this but now my scroll-to-fixed-navbar jquery code isn't working.

https://jsfiddle.net/9vugv3n5/3/

```
var elementPosition = $('#header_nav').offset();

$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
        $('#header_nav').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
    } else {
        $('#header_nav').css('position', 'static');
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't give width: 300%; to #About. Make it 100%. It will work.

```
#About {
    background-color: #c4f9de;
    width: 100%;
}
```

"ID" should be unique. As per the jsfiddle example you have used #About twice.

Comment: i want to make left, right and middle 100% of width of the browser screen and i didn't use it more then once in html. I don't know if i'm getting something wrong

Comment: As per your code you have provided a width 300% to the parent i.e.  section#About. So the child divs i.e. div#middle, div#left, div#right takes width as 33.33% of 300%. If you scroll left to right, you would find out the exact issue. So if you change the width of section#About to 100%. it will work for you.

Comment: Sorry but i don't think this is the solution to my problem, maybe you didn't undestand well what i am trying to acomplish because of my poor explanation but i have now edited the post and provided a little sketch which imo provides a better description of things i want :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at flex-box. I haven't looked at your code deeply but, the problem you describe should be fixable by using flex-box